# How is the the net probability mentioned in EIP-55 calculated?

Tags: addresses, hash

In [EIP-55](https://github.com/Ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-55.md#rationale), it says:

> the net probability that a randomly generated address if mistyped will accidentally pass a check is 0.0247%

I am curious about how this probability is calculated and tried to calculate it, such as:

```
>> (16 ** 40) / (22 ** 40)
2.9369197064733926e-06
```

I think there are 16 characters for an origin address(`abcdef0123456789`) and there are 22 characters for a formatted address(`abcdefABCDEF0123456789`). But the outcome is not 0.0247%.